# Insert query locking down the entire DB and not responding

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a almost fully normalized (3NF) database for a ticket booking/purchase application, widely used throughout my country by a traveling company. It is in **MySQL**.

Recently it has exceeded 1GB (DUMP SIZE) and queries has become sufficiently slower. In order to reduce query time and db size (greatly), I am thinking about doing this cheating.

I'm going to dump all the data into a offline server where the management can view history older than 3 months. Then remove all the old data (by querying) from the online database. Trust me older data isn't that much important in here.

The only old data that is important that is how many time a registered passenger has travelled with the company. Even though it's probably not the greatest idea, I'm just planning on adding up an **integer value to the "passenger" table where I'll be keeping the old count.** As simple as that.

*But here's the problem. When I run this following query, my phpMyAdmin (or adminer) hangs up. So does the server and somehow the table gets locked. It doesn't work unless I restart the Server.*

Here's the query. It's pretty

```sql
UPDATE `passenger` 
SET `CountAddition` = (
                       SELECT COUNT(1) FROM booking 
                       WHERE booking.Passenger = passenger.ID
                       )
WHERE 1
```

I've given it around 30 minutes to run. It never ends. What might have gone wrong with it? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Also, if there is a better alternative than this one, please suggest.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need `WHERE 1` if you want it to always run. Just omit the WHERE and it will work on all records.

Comment: make a SELECT first, and see what the results are.

Comment: why where 1? also, if your table not designed properly, and for large data it might takes a while...

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the WHERE 1. I knew that already. but as I was testing the query in phpMyAdmin, I didn't remove the WHERE 1.

I don't think it should have made any difference but after removing the WHERE clause, the query finished (and in less than 30 mins) successfully. That's plain weird but I guess my jobs done.

Answer (score 0):

**Subquery** will not work without the group by and that is why it is not showing any progress.

Answer (score 0):

you should include some verbose messages to your scripts.

also do the select first and loop through the results updating the table. If your using MyISM tables then the whole table gets locked when your doing an update to a row. You can try switching to innodb. Also ensure there is an index on `booking.Passenger` and `passenger.ID`

Comment: I tested by using SELECT first, then updated. It didn't take more than 6 minutes. The engine is InnoDB and passenger.ID is Primary key and booking.Passenger is index and foreign key to passenger.ID.